# Don't auto focus QDialog fields

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am using QtDesigner (4.8.7) to build a QDialog which will serve as the main interaction point for a QGIS plugin I am creating. Most of the user input is entered through various QLineEdit fields, some of which have a `placeholderText` set.

Unfortunately, every time the QDialog is opened, a QLineEdit field is immediately selected (i.e. it receives focus), which causes the placeholderText to disappear in order to allow the user to enter text. Therefore, I'm wondering if it's possible to create a QDialog which does not automatically focus on any field.
This would allow the end user of my plugin to inspect the place holder texts before entering any value themselves.

I'm currently initializing the QDialog as follows:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui  as QTG
import PyQt4.QtCore as QTC

from dialog_ui   import Ui_dialog

class UI (object):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        # iface is just a way to interact with QGIS
        self.iface     = iface

        self.container = QTG.QDialog()
        self.ui        = Ui_dialog()

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.ui.setupUi(self.container)
        # Custom ui setup code follows after this...

    # Called by an external function
    def show(self):
        self.container.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Tab Order Editing Mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-tab-order.html) in Qt Designer.

Start the tab-ordering on some widget that doesn't have placeholder text. That widget will get the initial focus.

Alternatively, just call `setFocus()` on an appropriate widget before showing the dialog.

Comment: This works initially, but the problem occurs again once the user selects any field.

Comment: @mathsaey. Yes - that's why I gave the alternative solution of calling `setFocus()` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually went for a combination of ekhumoro's answer and the solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472996/3329884). The gist of the solution is to use `clearFocus()` on the QLineEdit to force it to lose focus.

I decided to make the QLineEdit lose focus when the user clicks on another location of the overarching QDialog. The code ends up looking like this:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui  as QTG
import PyQt4.QtCore as QTC

from dialog_ui   import Ui_dialog

class CustomDialog (QTG.QDialog):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        focusWidget = QTG.QApplication.focusWidget()
        if focusWidget:
            focusWidget.clearFocus()

class UI (object):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        # iface is just a way to interact with QGIS
        self.iface     = iface

        self.container = CustomDialog()
        self.ui        = Ui_dialog()

        # Rest of the code remains unchanged
```

Comment: Instead of tying into a `mousePressEvent` and assuming that it's the only way focus might be changed, you should tie into `QApplication::focusChanged` and remove focus from any children of your dialog.