# Make QListWidget not selectable (PyQt5)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm making a sidebar using a custom QListWidget, and I want to make it not selectable. I'm not asking about making the *items* not selectable, I'm talking about the QListWidget itself. On the theme WhiteSur on KDE, I can't select the QListWidget itself, only the items, which is good. But using the Breeze KDE theme, I can select the QListWidget, which gives the list a blue outline. How can I make it so you can't select the QListWidget?

How it works with Breeze theme:

Not selected:
[image: Not selected]

Selected:
[image: Selected]

What I want:

Not selected:
[image: Not selected]

Selected:
[image: Selected]

Comment: That's not a "selection", it's the focus highlight indicator. Unless you specifically want the current style behavior, why can't you just set a basic stylesheet border on the widget?

Comment: Thanks, I needed to search for "focus" instead of "selectable". Found an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472996/13956165

Comment: Wait. I'm afraid that you may be confusing the *display* behavior and the *interaction* one. While focus and focus display are obviously closely related, the should **not** be confused. Based on this question (and your previous one), it seems that your issue is about the *display*: you just don't like that border. But that border is not just there for fancy purposes: it makes visible to the user that that list widget is *currently focused*, meaning that it currently accepts keyboard events (which may be essential for keyboard navigation, like using tab or arrow keys).

Comment: If your issue is just about displaying purposes, clearing the focus from the widget is not only a wrong choice: it's a **terrible** one. You may not be used to it, but keyboard navigation is a basic UI concept that is still valid nowadays: for instance, using arrow keys to switch between items. But that's not all: you should never ignore people with visual impairments, as they can only rely on "virtual hints" that are also based on current focus; if you clear that just because you don't like the look of your list, you prevent some people to use it (people who would never care about that look).

Comment: So, if your purpose is just about displaying the list without that "highlighted" border, than you should solve *that* aspect, not a different one. That can be achieved: for instance, use a basic stylesheet border as written above, or eventually using a [proxy style](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html). Please, be really aware about these aspects: 1. not everybody sees what you see (not only physically, it also depends on their OS and setup); 2. not everybody is really interested in what you *expect* them to see; 3. somebody is not even able to *see*, but your program still has to be *usable*.

Comment: Ah, didn't think about keyboard navigation. I might just leave it as is then. It would be too much effort to try and make it look good on every theme.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the *selected* state of a widget with the *focus*, which handles keyboard input: a *focused* widget will receive keyboard events and eventually handle them.

A widget (specifically, an element of a widget) can be selected and still not having focus; consider having two text areas: you may only type in one of them, which is the one that is currently *focused*, but that doesn't prevent the other to have some of its text *selected*. Note that there is the exception of QLineEdit which, by default, *deselects* the text when it loses focus.

The same goes for item views: the view could be focused and not having any item selected, or it can have selected items and still not being focused, because another widget (or window) currently is.

Note that *showing* a "focus hint" is an expected behavior of a GUI in a desktop environment: it allows the user to immediately see which widget is the currently focused one, so that they know that they can directly use the keyboard to interact with it instead of having to click it (or focus it using tab keys).

Imagine having a UI with *many* text fields: the user has to know what is the focused one at first glance, without having to click it or wait for the blinking cursor to appear (meaning that they have to check *all* fields for that).

So, a well designed UI should, among other things, *always* show a visible focus hint, not only for text inputs, but even for item views, because that's important for keyboard navigation (eg. using the arrow keys to *select* items). While keyboard navigation is much less common nowadays (common people were not used to it even before touch interfaces), that should never be underestimated.

Still, if you want to go on with that, it *is* possible, and the solution is quite simple: use a [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html).

All Qt item views inherit from QFrame (QListWidget » QListView » QAbstractItemView » QAbstractScrollArea » QFrame), which draws its frame using the QStyle [`drawControl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawControl) function with the `CE_ShapedFrame` control type. If we override that function, get that type and the widget is a QAbstractItemView, we can just override the [`state`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html#state-var) of the related [QStyleOptionFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionframe.html) style option ignoring the `State_HasFocus` state:

```py
class Proxy(QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, ctl, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if (
            ctl == self.CE_ShapedFrame 
            and isinstance(widget, QAbstractItemView)
            and opt.state & self.State_HasFocus
        ):
            opt.state &= ~self.State_HasFocus
        super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(Proxy())
# ...
```